# Right Adjoint are left exact

Tags: category-theory, abelian-categories, adjoint-functors

While reading $Ravi$ $Vakil's$ notes , I got stuck at proving **right adjoints** are **left exact** in abelian category.

I am able to show **limits** commute with **limits** and **right adjoints** . He hinted to prove above result that kernel are limit , which seems fine to me . But how to use this to prove  above result.

Any hint would be welcome.

Comment: I don't quite understand your question. You have written down all the arguments. What else is left for the proof? Maybe you should elaborate on what your problems are, so that it is easier for us to help you.

Comment: @Claudius to show right adjoint functor say F is left exact , given a exact sequence 0 -> A -> B ->C , we want 0 -> F(A) ->F(B) -> F(C) is exact , but my doubt is how is it following from above result which i have proved

Comment: Please don't use math mode for emphasis, it looks terrible... Just surround the text by single asterisks to get *italics* (like you did with double asterisks to get **bold**).

Comment: ok sorry about that

Comment: Just remember that $0\to A\to B \to C$ is exact precisely if $A$ is the kernel of $B\to C$.

Comment: @asdq Thank you, i got confused